# C# MongoDB not serializing System.Security.Claims.Claim

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I seem to be unable to serialize `Claim` - what am I doing wrong? Other object serializations using this method works fine.

**Code**

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("TEST");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Claim>("Claims");

var payload = new Claim("name", "value");
collection.InsertOne(payload);
```

**Result**

An object gets inserted into MongoDB but nothing other than `_id` gets set/populated.

[image]

*Using .NET Core 2.0.x and MongoDB.Driver 2.5.0.*

**Update 1**

Mapping members manually seems to work; it's just when it's auto-mapped that it seems to fail.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Claim>(cm =>
{
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Issuer);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.OriginalIssuer);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Properties);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Subject);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Type);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Value);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.ValueType);
    cm.MapCreator(c => new Claim(c.Type, c.Value, c.ValueType, c.Issuer, c.OriginalIssuer, c.Subject));
});
```

Comment: most probably because Claim properties(Type and Value) don't have public setters, which would mean that deserialization wouldn't produce a valid object

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic: that makes sense; thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Claim` class must be manually mapped due having no parameterless constructor and no public setters.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Claim>(cm =>
{
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Issuer);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.OriginalIssuer);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Properties);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Subject);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Type);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Value);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.ValueType);
    cm.MapCreator(c => new Claim(c.Type, c.Value, c.ValueType, c.Issuer, c.OriginalIssuer, c.Subject));
});
```